# ZF2 expire CAPTCHA value after validation

Tags: php, zend-framework2, captcha

I am using ZF2 Captcha form element like this:

```
  $captchaImage = new CaptchaImage(  array(
            'font' => dirname(__DIR__).'/../../../../public/fonts/arial.ttf',
            'width' => 150,
            'height' => 75,
            'dotNoiseLevel' => 40,
            'lineNoiseLevel' => 3 ,
            'wordLen' => 5
        )
    );
    $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Captcha',
        'name' => 'captcha',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Security Question',
            'captcha' => $captchaImage,
        ),
    ));
```

After using `isValid()` function I want to set this CAPTCHA code expired for later validations like this:

```
if($form->isValid())
{
    //set captcha expired
}
else
    echo 'invalid';
```

I need this to stop multiple form submission via browser refresh button. In case user press refresh button the validator accept the old CAPTCHA info. Is there any way for this?

Comment: The main problem is form multiple submission which is not solved either with captcha nor csrf element